# Navigate to a page from a tab within a TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a simple Xamarin.Forms app with a main page as TabbedPage which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="PrismSample.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PrismSample.Views"
    Title="Main Page"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Page1">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:OnePage Title="Page 1" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="Page2">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:TwoPage Title="Page 2" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

On the page "OnePage" I have a button. When I tap on that button I want to navigate to a page named "ThreePage".

OnPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="PrismSample.Views.OnePage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="20" Spacing="20">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Page 1" />
            <Button
                x:Name="Button1"
                Command="{Binding ClickMeCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="Open Page 3" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

OnePageViewModel:

```
namespace PrismSample.ViewModels
{
    public class OnePageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;
        public DelegateCommand ClickMeCommand { private set; get; }

        public OnePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
            ClickMeCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await ClickedAsync(), () => true);

            Debug.WriteLine($"NavigationStack: {this.navigationService.GetNavigationUriPath()}", nameof(OnePageViewModel));
        }

        public Task ClickedAsync()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"You clicked me!", nameof(OnePageViewModel));

            return navigationService.NavigateAsync("ThreePage");
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace PrismSample
{
    public partial class App
    {
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var result = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage");

            if(!result.Success)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<OnePage, OnePageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TwoPage, TwoPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ThreePage, ThreePageViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the following:
When tapping on the button a navigation to the page "ThreePage" is done within the first tab. I also expected to have a "Back" button in the navigation bar.

What happens:
Nothing in the first tab. But if I switch to the second tab it shows the page "ThreePage" but also without a "Back" button.

What is going wrong here???

I have attached my project here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuu2wo5zqhp52gk/08-TabbedNavigation.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating via TabbedPages is broken in the latest `Prism` released version (8.0.0.1909).

[[Bug] Navigation when in Tabbed Pages doesn't change currently selected tab #2218](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2218)

(It seems they finally have fixed this issue but they haven't released a new version until now)

So downgrade `Prism.DryIoc` to 7.2.0.1422 or wait for the next Prism release...